# CALL always throws exception on SSTORE

Tags: solidity, storage

```
this.call(bytes4(keccak256("setGBA(uint32)")), 12);
```

How to call function by string name? I can't modify store in function. How to do this?

Comment: The call itself looks correct. Have you tried increasing gaslimit? How do you know it fails on SSTORE?

Comment: @medvedev1088 I tried to increase but  no results https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0xd22a6d37141304467a9a5435d6eab8b9226d81eec087e95a9b53de2ba490674d

Look at this transaction exception on SSTORE

Comment: The required gas for sstore is 5000 but only 1020 remains.

Comment: @medvedev1088, but how to increase I tried this.call.gas() but with no luck

Comment: When you send the transaction (not message call) you can set gas limit. In the previous tx it’s  26558 which is not enough.

Comment: @medvedev1088, Thank you! But do you know how to setup gaslimit for tx in the remix ide?

Comment: On the Run tab there is a field called Gas limit

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the gas limit of the transaction. In Remix, you can set the gas limit on the Run tab.